# Does a horizontal line represent a function?

Tags: functions

I know that a vertical line has infinite outputs. For that it cannot be a function. What about horizontal lines? Because a horizontal line has only one output.

Comment: We can define functions where the domain is an ordered set of objects and therefore more than one, for example two real numbers. 

Something which can have many different outs in a domain for the same input is sometimes called a manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. It represents a function that gives the same output no matter what input you give it. Usually written as $f(x)=a$ (so, for instance, $f(x)=5$ is one such function), and called a *constant function*.

Comment: and what's the domain of it?

Comment: @Steve Whatever you want it to be. For each domain and each codomain and each point / element in the codomain, there is exactly one constant function with that domain, codomain and output value.

Answer (score 0):

A horizontal line represents a function (constant function). 
It is the case that a function can have the same value for many different $x$ inputs. 
It passes the vertical line test. 
A function cannot have have $2$ values of $y$ for the same $x$ but The horizontal line has one $y$ value for every $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. No, a horizontal line is not a function. It is the graph of a function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).